# Overwrite category head title

Tags: plugins, functions, themes

Is there any way to overwrite a `<head><title>Category title</title></head>` tag?

Let's say i have a "Videos" category, when user point's his browser to `www.website.com/category/videos/`, the page title (this one in `head` section) is **Videos**. What i need to do is to somehow overwrite it to display **Archive** string (without changing this category title), it can be hardcoded in some way cause i have just this one single category.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`wp_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title) filter to modify the output of the [`wp_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) function.

quick example based on the example from Codex:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpa66574_title_filter', 10, 3 );

function wpa66574_title_filter( $title, $sep, $seplocation ) {
    // account for $seplocation
    $left_sep = ( $seplocation != 'right' ? ' ' . $sep . ' ' : '' );
    $right_sep = ( $seplocation != 'right' ? '' : ' ' . $sep . ' ' );

    $page_type = '';

    // get special page type (if any)
    if( is_category( 'videos' ) ) $page_type = $left_sep . 'Archive' . $right_sep;

    // get the page number
    if( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) $page_num = $left_sep. get_query_var( 'paged' ) . $right_sep; // on index
    elseif( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) $page_num = $left_sep . get_query_var( 'page' ) . $right_sep; // on single
    else $page_num = '';

    // concoct and return title
    return $page_type . $title . $page_num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your theme, in the `header.php` template, just find the line with the `<title>` tag, something like this:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '' ); ?></title>
```

Then check which page type you're on and edit as necessary:

```
<title>
    <?php if ( is_category( 'video' ) ) echo 'Archive: '; ?>
    <?php wp_title( '' ); ?>
</title>
```

Keep in mind that themes and plugins mess with the `<title>` tag all the time, so you might run into conflicts. If you don't want to mess with your theme directly, try a plugin that can handle this, like [WordPress SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/).